# Socket Server in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, sockets, server

Is possible to create a socket server (NOT socket client), in iOS and Android?

The socket server will (in iOS/Android) only listen to incoming clients and react only based on that.

Comment: Do you want to make android mobile react as a server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! 
just need to get `phone IMEI` Instead of user information!
but in this way don't need to sign up user
just need and in `onResume` get `IMEI` and send this to the server instead of user

Answer (score 0):

Yes. And here is a working chess game example between server socket on Android and client socket on iOS.

Android chess in Kotlin:
https://github.com/zhijunsheng/chess-kotlin-andr

iOS chess in Swift:
https://github.com/zhijunsheng/chess-uikit-ios

There is [a demo video](https://youtu.be/u7iDc_DaYeM) too.